# Rails 3 autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I've some problem. Can anyone help me with my mistake?
I'm using rails 3 autocomplete gem from https://github.com/mikeauclair/rails3-jquery-autocomplete
and follow all instructions, but have error:

```
undefined method `autocomplete_user_nickname' for #<Message:0xa09374c>
```

My routes:

```
resources :messages do
   get :autocomplete_user_nickname, :on => :collection
end
```

MessagesController.rb:

```
autocomplete  :user, :nickname
```

My new.html.erb:

```
<% form_for @message, :url => user_messages_path(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :sender_id %>
  <%= f.autocomplete_field :autocomplete_user_nickname, autocomplete_user_nickname_messages_path %>
  <%= f.text_field :subject %>
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
  <%= submit_tag "Send" %>
<% end %>
```

What I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Readme at the project you linked, your form field is not correct. You have:

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :autocomplete_user_nickname, autocomplete_user_nickname_messages_path %>
```

The Readme says it should be:

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :user_nickname, autocomplete_user_nickname_messages_path %>
```

**[Edit]**

Based on your comments, I assume you have something like the following:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class MessagesController
  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end
end
```

I think you should use something like the following for your view:

```
<%= form_for(@message) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :id => "real_user_id"
  To: <%= autocomplete_field_tag 'throwaway_user', '',
          autocomplete_user_nickname_messages_path,
          :size => 75, :id_element => '#real_user_id' %> <br />
  Subject: <%= f.text_field :subject %>
  etc...
<% end %>
```

This way, the autocomplete field is just some throwaway data, but when it autocompletes it'll update the value of the *real* user ID tag (with the ID `real_user_id`) to be the ID of the autocompleted user.

**[Another Edit]**

Since I wasn't sure what the problem was after your last comment, I decided to make a small app myself. It seems to be working fine for me, so I assume there's something up with your model.

You can see what I did to implement this at [this GitHub compare view](https://github.com/BinaryMuse/so_5521473_autocomplete/compare/master...autocomplete); I left out the boring stuff, like installing jQuery and jQuery UI. You can see the app actually working in the screenshots in [the readme](https://github.com/BinaryMuse/so_5521473_autocomplete/tree/autocomplete#readme). Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, sure, my mistake, but error still exists: undefined method `user_nickname' for #<Message:0xa118f50>

Comment: What is the name of the field on the `Message` model that you want the autocomplete to populate? That should be the first parameter to `f.autocomplete_field`, just like other form helpers.

Comment: No, I need to autocomplete user nicknames (User model), user clicks to the "New message' link and user nickname needs to be autocomplete.

Comment: If you're not populating an attribute on the model, you should probably use the `autocomplete_field_tag` invocation as demonstrated under the "View" section of the Readme. If you need the ID of the user, you can create an actual `f.user_id` field or whatever on the `Message` object and use the "Getting the object id" method (also in the Readme) to update the form accordingly.

Comment: I've updated my answer according to my last comment. Does that get you any closer?

Comment: Yes, now page renders normally, but i can see in the firebug  errors:ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in MessagesController#autocomplete_user_nickname

Couldn't find User without an ID

Comment: I use: <%= autocomplete_field_tag 'user_nickname', '', autocomplete_user_nickname_messages_path, :id_element => :sender_id %> In the Message model I've fields sender_id and recipient_id fields.

Comment: The `:id_element` needs to be a jQuery-style selector, e.g. `#id_of_element`--however, I don't think that's causing your ActiveRecord errors. Are you getting any sort of backtrace you can post?

Comment: Ok, I understand. But autocomplete method doesn't returns me user nickname, any XHR returns me 404 error...

Comment: Stacktraces:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    in MessagesController#autocomplete_user_nickname
Couldn't find User without an ID

Comment: app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:59:in `set_user'

activerecord (3.0.5) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:279:in `find_with_ids'
activerecord (3.0.5) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:107:in `find'
activerecord (3.0.5) lib/active_record/base.rb:439:in `find'

Comment: I've updated my answer with a working example, source code is on GitHub. Not sure what's up with your own app. Hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: Just want you to know that September 13 2014 your answer helped a 22 year old programmer at 6:11am EST who is building a rails app late into the night. I thank you wholeheartedly. <3

Answer (score 2):

I think much better you use autocomplete.git. It works in Rails 3. It's easy.

https://github.com/rails/auto_complete/pull/9

But if you to know to use the jquery gem, I ask to you to put your solution and where WE are making mistake.

Bye....

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `:id_element` option is broken, and if you install from this [github fork](https://github.com/juniorz/rails3-jquery-autocomplete) it will work

`gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete', :git => 'git://github.com/juniorz/rails3-jquery-autocomplete.git'`